# npm show with private npm repository

Tags: node.js, npm, repository

For awhile I'm using a private npm repository to publish some of my modules. All is working fine besides one little detail - I cannot make **npm show** to work.

**[Assumptions]**

- Lets assume that I have a private npm repo @ http://my-repo.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/npm/ (yes I'm using Nexus).
- Lets assume I have changed my npm registry:

  ```
  npm set registry http://my-repo.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/npm/
  ```
- Lets assume I have my-module published to my-repo.

**[My intentions]**

I want to be able to check the latest (or may be all) version(s) of my-module. However using the standard ***npm show*** or ***npm view*** commands results in performing a search in npmjs.org and therefore doesn't find any version of my-package.

**[Question]**

Is there a npm way to see the version of my-package from the described scenario above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use http request.In this case, is `http://my-repo.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/npm/[your package name]` to get package's information, then parse response object.

You can parse link into browser to see response directly